# Captured Image Squeezed After Taking a Picture : Swift

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation

Short and simple, My captured image gets squeezed from both sides when loading it on the preview.

Long version: I am currently using the CameraManager Pod found at https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager/blob/master/camera/CameraManager.swift. My problem is that after I take a picture, it squeezes the image a little bit on both sides. The width is not what I see. The bounds of my preview (what I see through the camera) is `view.frame.bounds` and my bounds of the imageView (what I just captured) is `preview.frame.bounds`. If need be, I can take a image of whats happening if you need more information.

If you need the code just comment and I can show you. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to set contentMode for that imageView

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I wasn't setting the contentMode of my image view. All I had to do was add this line

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

Duplicate of:

[How to manage UIImageView content mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode)

and

[capture image is stretched using avcapture session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478832/capture-image-is-stretched-using-avcapture-session)

Sorry for posting a question without doing thorough research. I wasn't Google-ing the right query.